# Merging lists of dataframes in order

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have 3 lists of 3 dataframes each:

```
l1 = [df1_1, df1_2, df1_3]
l2 = [df2_1, df2_2, df2_3]
l3 = [df3_1, df3_2, df3_3]
```

I am trying to find a way to iterate through the lists to merge the dataframes at the same list index position, so that I get the equivalent of:

```
l_new = [df1_1.merge(df2_1).merge(df3_1),
         df1_2.merge(df2_2).merge(df3_2),
         df1_3.merge(df2_3).merge(df3_3)]
```

I cannot, however, quite get my head around the correct iteration and merge syntax.  I tried:

```
[(item).merge((item) in l2).merge((item) in l3) for item in l1]
```

but received:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Comment: do you have some code to generate a dataset that goes with the problem? :)

Comment: Nothing short and concise, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good night's sleep and I was able to find a suitable answer:

```
l_new = [l1[i].merge(l2[i]).merge(l3[i]) for i in range(len(l1))]
```